# usepackage doesn't load variables

Tags: use-package, load

I use doom emacs.

Can you tell me why sometimes not all variables/functions are loaded? I use `(usepackage! org-roam-bibtex)`, but `org-xxx` variables cannot be found with `describe-variable`. I need to require `(org-roam-bibtex)` separately. What is going on here?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Should be `(use-package!`?